# jquery addclass problem

Tags: jquery, css, image, class, addition

im trying to make a border to a image when i Hover it but it dont add it :S but i have try console.log and it show the text i have write but it dosent add the class to it :S

This is my code

```
<style>
.test {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
</style>
// add a class to the image that is focus on
$('#small-image .thumb').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('test');
        console.log('hover');
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('test');
        console.log('out');
});
```

Comment: Why are you using jQuery and not css? `.thumb:hover { border: 1px solid #000 }`?

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddler.net example of what you are are doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need javascript for this?

Markup:

```
<div id="foo"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#foo {width:50px; height:50px; border: 1px solid blue}
#foo:hover {border-color: red}
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/JndDd/

Comment: @Neal For IE 7 and below; not an issue in my opinion.

Comment: okay i dident think of that :), but it still dont work :S i try #small-image.thumb:hover {
    border: 5px solid blue;
}

Comment: @ole, try post your code on jsfiddle.net and then post the link here in a new question

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem is that your base CSS overrides the styles in the `test` class?

If you don't care about IE6, you can do the whole thing with CSS:

```
#small-image.thumb:hover {
    border: 5px solid blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to run just fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/eDyTg/1/

Whatever the problem is, it isn't with what you posted.

Answer (score 0):

trying removing the space in your selector:

```
$('#small-image .thumb')
```

to

```
$('#small-image.thumb')
```